# Curl content_type always the default php

Tags: php, curl

```
$file = file_get_contents($path, true);
$url = "https://secure.efaxdeveloper.com/EFax_WebFax.serv";

//setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
));
// Following line is compulsary to add as it is:
$data = 'id=' . urlencode("2313125942") . '&name2=' . urlencode($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r('<pre>');
   print_r($info);
print_r('</pre>');
```

In my code above I set the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and post data

```
$data = 'id=' . urlencode("2313125942") . '&name2=' . urlencode($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

But the result of the curl_getinfo()

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://secure.efaxdeveloper.com/EFax_WebFax.serv
    [content_type] => text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 226
    [request_size] => 175
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.65944
    [namelookup_time] => 0.150319
    [connect_time] => 0.183032
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.261438
    [size_upload] => 531848
    [size_download] => 833
    [speed_download] => 1263
    [speed_upload] => 806514
    [download_content_length] => 833
    [upload_content_length] => 531848
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.293966
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 104.12.131.61
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 127.31.12.152
    [local_port] => 52972
)
```

My question is why content_type is [content_type] => text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 and i can't see the post data. I'am a beginner in curl can anyone explain what is wrong in my code?

Comment: The `content-type` from `curl_getinfo` is the content type of the response, not the request.  This means in response to your HTTP request, they are sending back an HTML webpage.   If you want more information about your request, see `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` from http://php.net/curl_setopt.  Also, cURL with automatically set the content-type of the request for you, so there's no need to specify it unless you explicitly need to override it.

Comment: I want to see all of the information about my request i 
thought curl_getinfo() function will do this thank you for this information.

Comment: i tried the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true) how can i print the information of my request ?

Comment: If you're running it from a browser, you'll need to add: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));` to see it.  Then you'll probably need to view-source to see it formatted properly.  Also, are you actually trying to upload a file?  If so, see http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php depending on your PHP version.  Otherwise prepend the filename with an '@' to cause it to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my web application is built with Yii framework I used [EHttpClient extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ehttpclient/) instead. @drew010 Thank you for your comments.

```
$file = file_get_contents($path, true);

Yii::import('ext.EHttpClient.*');

$client = new EHttpClient('https://secure.efaxdeveloper.com/EFax_WebFax.serv', array(
    'maxredirects' => 3,
    'timeout'      => 30,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'adapter'      => 'EHttpClientAdapterCurl'));

$client->setParameterPost(array('id'=>urlencode("2313125942"), 'xml'=>urlencode($file)));


SiteHelper::printShow($client);

$response = $client->request("POST");
```

I was able to see my request information by print the $client w/c the EHttpClient object.

```
EHttpClient Object
(
    [config:protected] => Array
        (
            [maxredirects] => 3
            [strictredirects] => 
            [useragent] => EHttpClient
            [timeout] => 30
            [adapter] => EHttpClientAdapterCurl
            [httpversion] => 1.1
            [keepalive] => 
            [storeresponse] => 1
            [strict] => 1
            [output_stream] => 
            [encodecookies] => 1
            [rfc3986_strict] => 
            [content-type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        )

    [adapter:protected] => 
    [uri:protected] => EUriHttp Object
        (
            [_username:protected] => 
            [_password:protected] => 
            [_host:protected] => secure.efaxdeveloper.com
            [_port:protected] => 443
            [_path:protected] => /EFax_WebFax.serv
            [_query:protected] => 
            [_fragment:protected] => 
            [_regex:protected] => Array
                (
                    [alphanum] => [^\W_]
                    [escaped] => (?:%[\da-fA-F]{2})
                    [mark] => [-_.!~*'()\[\]]
                    [reserved] => [;\/?:@&=+$,]
                    [unreserved] => (?:[^\W_]|[-_.!~*'()\[\]])
                    [segment] => (?:(?:(?:[^\W_]|[-_.!~*'()\[\]])|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2})|[:@&=+$,;])*)
                    [path] => (?:\/(?:(?:(?:[^\W_]|[-_.!~*'()\[\]])|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2})|[:@&=+$,;])*)?)+
                    [uric] => (?:[;\/?:@&=+$,]|(?:[^\W_]|[-_.!~*'()\[\]])|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))
                )

            [_scheme:protected] => https
        )

    [headers:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [method:protected] => GET
    [paramsGet:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [paramsPost:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2313125942
            [xml] => The%encoded%url%xml%data
        )

    [cookiejar:protected] => 
    [last_request:protected] => 
    [last_response:protected] => 
    [redirectCounter:protected] => 0
    [_unmaskStatus:protected] => 
    [_queryBracketsEscaped:protected] => 1
)
```